How can I rewrite this block of if / Else if into a more structured, condensed and optimal way. (C#)
In C# .NET. This block of if/else if works fine, but its getting cumbersome to maintain and read. I want a more optimized writing style.

if (Globals.SRSI < 10 && Globals.SRSI != 0 && Globals.ATR14 != 0) //Low Stochastic Entry Long Strategy
{ 
    dStochRSIPriceLong = markPrice - (0.1 * Globals.ATR14); 
    ECStrategy = "Stochastic Long"; 
} 
else if (Globals.RSI < 20 && Globals.RSI != 0 && Globals.ATR14 != 0) //RSI Rebound Long Strategy
{ 
    dRSIPriceLong = markPrice - (0.2 * Globals.ATR14); 
    ECStrategy = "Rebound Long"; 
}
else if (Globals.MACDLINEPrevious < Globals.MACDSigLINEPrevious && Globals.MACDLINE > Globals.MACDSigLINE) //MACD Crossover Long Strategy
{
    dMACDCrossoverLong = markPrice - (0.2 * Globals.ATR14);
    ECStrategy = "Crossover Long";
}
else if (Math.Abs(markPrice - Globals.SMA25) > 300 && Globals.PreviousCandleLo > Globals.SMA25 && markPrice > Globals.SMA25 && Globals.SMA25 > Globals.SMA50 && Globals.SMA50 > Globals.SMA100) //Runaway Long Strategy
{
    dLoCandleLong = Globals.PreviousCandleLo;
    ECStrategy = "Runaway Long";
}                                                                            
else if (markPrice > Globals.SMA25 && Globals.SMA25 > Globals.SMA50 && Globals.SMA50 > Globals.SMA100) //Knife Long Strategy
{ 
    dMA2PriceLong = Globals.SMA25; 
    ECStrategy = "Knife Long"; 
}  
else if (markPrice > Globals.SMA50 && Globals.SMA50 > Globals.SMA100) //Moving Average Momentum Long Strategy
{ 
    dMAPriceLong = Globals.SMA50; 
    ECStrategy = "Momentum Long"; 
}                               
else if (markPrice > Globals.SMA100) //MA100 Breakout Long Strategy
{ 
    dPullbacksPriceLong = Globals.SMA100; 
    ECStrategy = "Breakout Long"; 
}                                                      
dPositionEntryPriceLong = SearchArray(markPrice, new List<double> { dStochRSIPriceLong, dRSIPriceLong, dMACDCrossoverLong, dLoCandleLong, dMA2PriceLong, dMAPriceLong, dPullbacksPriceLong });



Obviously there will still be if/else but I am hoping to not having this repetition. I tried to use a list with index but got lost in the complication of it all because I don't know how I can list a condition and action and then look it up.

Conditional to polymorphism

What does SearchArray do? It seem a bit strange that each case sets different variables, how does the rest of the code know if say dMAPriceLong has a valid value?

SearchArray finds the value closest to current price, this means its the valid strategy to follow. Most of the time the others are zero in any case. Not all statements can be true at the same time.

You can use a list of conditions and corresponding actions to make this block of if/else statements more structured, condensed, and easier to maintain. This can be achieved by creating a list of tuples or a custom class to hold the condition and action and then iterating through this list. Here's one way to do it using a custom class:
public class Strategy
{
    public Func<bool> Condition { get; set; }
    public Action Action { get; set; }
}

public void DetermineStrategy(double markPrice)
{
    double dStochRSIPriceLong = 0, dRSIPriceLong = 0, dMACDCrossoverLong = 0;
    double dLoCandleLong = 0, dMA2PriceLong = 0, dMAPriceLong = 0, dPullbacksPriceLong = 0;
    string ECStrategy = string.Empty;

    var strategies = new List<Strategy>
    {
        new Strategy
        {
            Condition = () => Globals.SRSI < 10 && Globals.SRSI != 0 && Globals.ATR14 != 0,
            Action = () => { dStochRSIPriceLong = markPrice - (0.1 * Globals.ATR14); ECStrategy = "Stochastic Long"; }
        },
        new Strategy
        {
            Condition = () => Globals.RSI < 20 && Globals.RSI != 0 && Globals.ATR14 != 0,
            Action = () => { dRSIPriceLong = markPrice - (0.2 * Globals.ATR14); ECStrategy = "Rebound Long"; }
        },
        new Strategy
        {
            Condition = () => Globals.MACDLINEPrevious < Globals.MACDSigLINEPrevious && Globals.MACDLINE > Globals.MACDSigLINE,
            Action = () => { dMACDCrossoverLong = markPrice - (0.2 * Globals.ATR14); ECStrategy = "Crossover Long"; }
        },
        new Strategy
        {
            Condition = () => Math.Abs(markPrice - Globals.SMA25) > 300 && Globals.PreviousCandleLo > Globals.SMA25 && markPrice > Globals.SMA25 && Globals.SMA25 > Globals.SMA50 && Globals.SMA50 > Globals.SMA100,
            Action = () => { dLoCandleLong = Globals.PreviousCandleLo; ECStrategy = "Runaway Long"; }
        },
        new Strategy
        {
            Condition = () => markPrice > Globals.SMA25 && Globals.SMA25 > Globals.SMA50 && Globals.SMA50 > Globals.SMA100,
            Action = () => { dMA2PriceLong = Globals.SMA25; ECStrategy = "Knife Long"; }
        },
        new Strategy
        {
            Condition = () => markPrice > Globals.SMA50 && Globals.SMA50 > Globals.SMA100,
            Action = () => { dMAPriceLong = Globals.SMA50; ECStrategy = "Momentum Long"; }
        },
        new Strategy
        {
            Condition = () => markPrice > Globals.SMA100,
            Action = () => { dPullbacksPriceLong = Globals.SMA100; ECStrategy = "Breakout Long"; }
        }
    };

    foreach (var strategy in strategies)
    {
        if (strategy.Condition())
        {
            strategy.Action();
            break;
        }
    }

    dPositionEntryPriceLong = SearchArray(markPrice, new List<double> { dStochRSIPriceLong, dRSIPriceLong, dMACDCrossoverLong, dLoCandleLong, dMA2PriceLong, dMAPriceLong, dPullbacksPriceLong });
}


The Strategy class encapsulates a condition and an action.
A list of Strategy objects is created, each holding a condition and
the corresponding action.
The DetermineStrategy method iterates through the list and executes
the action of the first strategy whose condition is met.

This approach makes it easier to maintain and read the conditions and actions. You can add, remove, or modify strategies without changing the structure of the DetermineStrategy method.

This is good. Looped if check and assignment of action directly. Also saves the use of variables in my original code. Nice one, thanks! (I cannot upvote this cause not enough rep myself, but this will be the one I try)

Very fine solution, I've used similar patterns often. Be aware however that this may cause issues with performance if executed rapidly; I think the lambda functions might be recreated on each call assuming it's not compiler-optimized (fixable by moving strategies outward a scope and replacing function locals with locals on the lambda (x, y, ...) => { }) as well as the removal of a JMP chain which moves it up a level of abstraction so you might hit heap memory more often but I'm not totally sure of that as I haven't seen native C take a hit from similar use of anonymous functions.

I'd suggest making a class for each "strategy"; looping through a list of all the strategies; and letting each one determine if it is applicable and if so contribute its result to a list of results. Then interpret the list, or assert it is size 1.
interface IStrategy{
    bool IsApplicable(Globals globals);
    Result result(Globals globals);
}

class StochasticLongStrategy: IStrategy{
    bool IsApplicable(Globals globals){
        return Globals.SRSI < 10 && Globals.SRSI != 0 && Globals.ATR14 != 0;
    }
    Result result(Globals globals){
        return Result(.....)
    }
}


List<IStrategy> strategies = {new StochasticLongStrategy(),..........}
List<Result> strategyResults = new();

foreach (IStrategy strategy in strategies) {
    if (strategy.IsApplicable(globals)) strategyResults.Add(strategy.Result(globals))
}

......interpret strategyResults here


You can follow this pattern to separate your "rules" from the logical flow of the application.
I didn't rewrite all of your code because if you're taking this approach to make your code more expressive and readable then what you name the functions is really important.
// strategies / functions / rules
Func<bool> lowStoEntryLongStrat = () => Globals.SRSI < 10 && Globals.SRSI != 0 && Globals.ATR14 != 0;
Func<bool> rsiREboundLongStrat = () => Globals.RSI < 20 && Globals.RSI != 0 && Globals.ATR14 != 0;

// procedure
if (lowStoEntryLongStrat()) //Low Stochastic Entry Long Strategy
{
    dStochRSIPriceLong = markPrice - (0.1 * Globals.ATR14);
    ECStrategy = "Stochastic Long";
}
else if (rsiREboundLongStrat()) //RSI Rebound Long Strategy
{
    dRSIPriceLong = markPrice - (0.2 * Globals.ATR14);
    ECStrategy = "Rebound Long";
}
// ...

You should also consider looking at F# or other functional languages to store your formulas and calculations in a more readable way.

bool lowStoEntryLongStrat => (conditional expression).  And then if (lowStoEntryLongStrat).  No need for the Func<T>.
